# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler' cannot fix - You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs"

Tags: npm, build, angular-cli

Log build error:

```
[error] Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler'
Require stack:
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\index.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build-impl.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:854:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:21:22
    at C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\TestNewCore\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:12:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
```

Package.json:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "testnewcore-app",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "Dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.10",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.20",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  }
}
```

Angular version check:

```
C:\Code\TestNewCore>ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 13.3.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: undefined
...

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.20
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.20
@angular/cli                      8.3.20
@angular/compiler-cli             8.2.14
@angular/language-service         8.2.14
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.20
@schematics/angular               8.3.20
@schematics/update                0.803.20
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.7.3
```

To avoid posting another duplicate I've already tried the following and it didnt work.  I've started over several times and still come up to the same result:

```
rm -r node_modules (or delete your node_modules folder manually)
npm cache clean (npm > v5 add --force so: npm cache clean --force)
npm install
```

Didn't work also:

```
npm uninstall angular-cli
npm install @angular/cli --save-dev
```

It's probably something silly that I just cannot see but it seems whatever I do and try to build I keep ending up with the same result.  I havent even been able to get the error to change.

I then did `npm i @angular/compiler` and it produced a new error: `You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This is an error.`

I then tried `npm cache clean --force` and `npm install` and `npm link` both had no impact on the error.

Comment: Additionally delete your lock file before you do a clean install. Also your TypeScript version is to high use `3.5.3` but that's a different error.

Comment: @fridoo did not work.  still same error

Comment: npm won't install your dependencies because you spelled `Dependencies` in your `package.json` with a capital `D`. It has to be lowercase: `dependencies`.

Comment: Interesting!!  So I made it lower case "d" and i found it wiped out my dependencies but the CLI.  So I added it back in and it works and now i got the typescript error.  What version should it be?

Comment: @Mike typescript@3.4.5

Comment: I found a better way to resolve the typescript error that worked perfectly:                   npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 <3.6.0"

Comment: Thanks for your help @fridoo and Maihan !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the compiler individually:

```
npm i @angular/compiler
```

Check the node_modules if the installation is successful with the above or with `@angular/cli`.

If the problem persists:

```
npm uninstall angular-cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install @angular/cli --save-dev
```

For error:

> You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs".

```
npm link
```

Comment: I see an improvement but a new error: You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This is an error.

Comment: @Mike `npm cache clean --force` and install again or maybe a simple `npm install`

Comment: @Mike `npm link`